# PHP-FPM 301 Redirect From Incorrect Socket Assignment

Tags: php, apache, sockets, redirect

This is my first post so if something does not look right let me know. I have an interesting problem. A little bit of background of the configuration in question. I have two web nodes behind a load-balanced proxy with HAproxy. These web nodes utilize `Apache`, and `PHP-FPM` with unix sockets. If a website requires `PHP`, A ProxyPassMatch directive will be assigned to the virtualhost. Example of a virtualhost that requires `PHP`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName  www.site1.com
  ServerAlias  site1.com
  DocumentRoot  /path/to/docroot/var/www
  ProxyPassMatch "^/(.*\.php(.*)?)$" "unix:/php-sockets/php5.6_site1.com.sock|fcgi://127.0.0.1/var/www"
</VirtualHost>
```

The pool configuration for the unix socket:

```
[site1.com]
prefix                  =               /path/to/docroot
chroot                  =               /path/to/docroot
user                    =               <logical uid>
group                   =               <logical gid>
listen                  =               /php-sockets/php5.6_site1.com.sock
chdir                   =               /
listen.owner            =               www-data
listen.group            =               www-data
pm                      =               dynamic
pm.max_children         =               5
pm.start_servers        =               2
pm.min_spare_servers    =               1
pm.max_spare_servers    =               3
```

Other sites will follow this standard configuration, with the exception of the domain name being different. The problem is, `PHP-FPM` is assigning the incorrect socket on some requests, causing a 301 redirect to the incorrect URL. For example, another site will have the same configuration as mentioned above, with a different domain name. On occasion, the FPM manager will assign a socket meant for `site2` to a request for `site1`. Causing the incorrect website to load. I have turned on very verbose logging on Apache to see how this is happening, but unfortunately, the most information I see is when `PHP-FPM` makes the assignment based on the request. There are no mentions of `site2.com's` socket in site1's virtualhost configuration. I'm at a loss for how this can occur.

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved. Had to set a flag in the `php.ini` file

```
opcache.validate_root=1
```